# Как более правильно вводить числа с клавиатуры (что из двух)?

Tags: python

Сначало я учил питон по сайтам и книге ("Automate the boring stuff with Python"). В них что-бы ввести, например, целое число, используется такой способ:

```
>>> a = int(input())
3
>>> a
3
```

Сейчас я докупил еще одну книгу ("Introduction to Programming Using Python"). В ней ввод этого же числа будет осуществляться следующим образом:

```
>>> a = eval(input())
3
>>> a
3
```

Как правильно?

Comment: если книга использует `eval(input())`, чтобы прочитать целое число, то следует крайне осторожно к её рекомендациям относится (лучше выкинуть и [использовать одну из (бесплатных) книг, упомянутых в метке python](http://stackoverflow.com/tags/python/info))

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Вот один из ответов на SO, в котором говориться что eval это [bad practice](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1832940/is-using-eval-in-python-a-bad-practice).

Если кратко:
Медленно и небезопасно.

Answer (score 0):

использовать eval(input()) - это вообще дико.
 Пользователь может ввести любую команду и она сразу же выполнится.